# How to properly pass App handler to other modules in Tauri?

Tags: rust, tauri

### Problem

In a Tauri app. I have this main function in `main.rs` and I'm trying to pass the app handle to the `system_tray.rs::get_system_tray` function.

I don't get how do you pass the app handle correctly

I get this error:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `tauri::SystemTray`
  found fn item `for<'a> fn(&'a tauri::AppHandle) -> tauri::SystemTray {system_tray::get_system_tray}`
```

In this line of the code below:

```rust
.system_tray(system_tray::get_system_tray)
```

### Code

#### main.rs

```rust
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(setup_handler)
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_store::Builder::default().build())
        .system_tray(system_tray::get_system_tray)
        .on_system_tray_event(system_tray::on_system_tray_event)
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![
            system_info::get_system_stats,
            cpu_info::get_cpu_stats
        ])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

#### system_tray.rs

```rust
use tauri::{AppHandle, CustomMenuItem, Manager, SystemTray, SystemTrayEvent, SystemTrayMenu, SystemTrayMenuItem};

pub fn get_system_tray(app: &AppHandle) -> SystemTray {
    let app_version = app.package_info().version.to_string();
    let title_text = format!("Sigma File Manager Next {}", app_version);
    let title = CustomMenuItem::new("title".to_string(), title_text).disabled();
    let show_main_window = CustomMenuItem::new("show_main_window".to_string(), "Open app window");
    let reload_main_window = CustomMenuItem::new("reload_main_window".to_string(), "Reload app window");
    let quit = CustomMenuItem::new("quit".to_string(), "Quit");
    let tray_menu = SystemTrayMenu::new()
        .add_item(title)
        .add_native_item(SystemTrayMenuItem::Separator)
        .add_item(show_main_window)
        .add_item(reload_main_window)
        .add_native_item(SystemTrayMenuItem::Separator)
        .add_item(quit);

    SystemTray::new().with_menu(tray_menu)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [`build`](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.SystemTray.html#method.build) the tray at runtime instead if you need an [`AppHandle`](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.AppHandle.html) for generating the [`SystemTray`](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.SystemTray.html) like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet])
        .setup(|app| {
            let handle = app.handle();

            let _tray_handle = system_tray::get_system_tray(&handle).build(app)?;

            Ok(())
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

This will also allow you to update the tray whenever needed.

Comment: Thanks for a solution, mate. Why do I need the `.build(app)` at the end? Can I do the following instead? ```let tray = system_tray::get_system_tray(&app.handle()); app.manage(tray);```

Comment: That seems to be the documented way for how to do it. Not sure if `app.manage` will work as well. However the [`build`](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/src/tauri/app/tray.rs.html#366-464) method does something different as can be seen in the source code.

Comment: Yep, the app.manage doesn't create the tray icon. It seems Tauri was calling the build() function automatically in the original code (when the tray function was in the chain after the setup)